# Rstudio (%in%) shortcut?

Tags: r, rstudio, shortcut

There are shortcuts in `R` e.g. cmd + shift + m for piping commands `%>%` in R Studio. This is great. What about a shortcut for `%in%` on Mac?

Comment: if you do `tools > modify kb shortcuts` then filter by "operator" or "insert" the pipe/assignment shortcut comes up but no other operators, so i'm guessing it isn't defined

Comment: `cmd + shift + m` is a shortcut for `shift + % + > + %`? what a time to be alive

Comment: haha, yeah you press the keys all at once, that's way quicker ;) @rawr

Answer (score 4):

Install the [extrainserts](https://konradzdeb.github.io/extraInserts/) package, which creates several Rstudio AddIns.
One of them inserts the `%in%` operator and automatically surrounds it by single spaces.

Then you can search for `Insert %in%` within the RStudio Keyboard Shortcuts Menu (access via e.g. `Tools` -> `Modify Keyboard Shortcuts`) and set your preferred keybinding.

Comment: Thanks, that sound promising!! I understand how I can add command but where can I assign the `%in%` output to a specific shortcut that I enter into the field with the corresponding name?  Sorry for asking again.